# Печать без диалогового окна

Tags: delphi, winapi

Имеется программа cablabel s3 lite для печати этикеток. В edit вводится штрих-код и при нажатии Enter файл отправляется на печать. Нужно, чтобы при отправке на печать не выводилось диалоговое окно печати и форма моей программы оставалась активной. Пытаюсь сделать с помощью функции ShellExecuteEx:

```delphi
procedure TForm1.EditBarcodeKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
const
  Dir = 'Labels\';
var
  SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  ExecuteFile: string;
begin
  if Key = 13 then
  begin
    ExecuteFile := Dir + EditBarcode.Text + '.stc';
    FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0);
    SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
    with SEInfo do
    begin
      fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
      Wnd := Application.Handle;
      lpVerb := 'print';
      lpFile := PChar(ExecuteFile);
      nShow := SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE;
    end;
    try
      Win32Check(ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo));
    finally
      EditBarcode.SetFocus;
      EditBarcode.SelectAll;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

но безрезультатно. Подскажите в какую сторону двигаться.

Comment: Используя для печати строноннее ПО - вы подчиняетесь правилам заложеным в ПО, и ваш вопрос никак не касается "печати без диалогового окна", абсолютно.

Comment: Вариант 1. Найдите программу которая печатает без диалогого окна. Вариант 2 - используйте хакерские штучки FindWindow, SendMessage - скройте окно и нажмите кнопку печать програмно. Средней сложноти, но реализовать можно. Вариант 3 - сформируйте сами картинку ШКИ и печатайте без использования стороннего ПО, мне кажется в сети есть библиотеки и описание ШКИ, и ничто не должно мешать вам нарисовать ШКИ самостоятельно либо с помощью либы, и отправить на печать.  Вариант 4 - посмотрите опции вашего ПО, возможно там есть slient verbose или что-то такое.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Задумка программы была такова: пользователь с помощью сканера сканирует штрих код, этот штрих код вставляется в Edit и далее на печать выводится файл, соответсвтующий штрих коду.

Answer (score 0):

Используя ShellExecuteEx, Вы вызываете какую-то программу, ассоциированную в Windows с данным расширением и действием (verb), при этом не особо управляете процессом.
Если Вы точно знаете, какую программу Вы хотите использовать и с какими аргументами (кажется, это Ваш случай), то используйте CreateProcess с подходящими аргументами.
Вот образец:

```
procedure WinExecM(const ACmdLine: String; const ACmdShow: UINT = SW_SHOWNORMAL);
var
  SI: TStartupInfo;
  PI: TProcessInformation;
  CmdLine: String;
begin
  Assert(ACmdLine <> '');

  CmdLine := ACmdLine;
  UniqueString(CmdLine);

  FillChar(SI, SizeOf(SI), 0);
  FillChar(PI, SizeOf(PI), 0);
  SI.cb := SizeOf(SI);
  SI.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  SI.wShowWindow := ACmdShow;

  SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
  {$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
  Win32Check(
    CreateProcess(nil, PChar(CmdLine), nil, nil, False,
      CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE {$IFDEF UNICODE}or CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT{$ENDIF},
      nil, nil, SI, PI)
  );
  {$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM ON}
  CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
  CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
end;
```

Этот способ более качественный. И, естественно, используйте нужный SI.dwFlags и SI.wShowWindow, чтобы скрыть окно печати.